# Dynamic Query JPA 2 Specification With CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have below table data:

```
Product Reason Qty
Pepsi   IN     10
Pepsi   Out    2
Pepsi   In     15
Pepsi   Out    5 
Coke    IN     100
Coke    Out    20
Coke    In     35
Coke    Out    25
Fanta   Out     55
```

and I want to get result like below:

```
Product Qty
Pepsi   18
Coke    90
Fanta   -55
```

for that I have got below query:

```sql
SELECT Product,
       SUM(CASE WHEN reason IN ('IN','REFUND') THEN Qty 
                WHEN reason IN ('OUT','WASTE') THEN -Qty
                ELSE NULL END) AS Qty
FROM stock
GROUP BY Product;
```

I want to use `JPA Specification` like used in this [link](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications), I am new to `JPA Specification` can someone please guide me?

I have got this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627704/how-to-use-criteriaquery-sum-of-custom-operation-on-some-cells) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462330/criteriabuilder-sum-using-selectcase) but I am not sure what is the correct question to solve the problem?

**EDIT:**

I have tried below code

```
@Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Stockdiary> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {

    Path reasonexpression = root.get("reason");
                    Path qtyexpression = root.get("qty");

                    List<String> inList = new ArrayList<String> ();
                    inList.add("IN");

                    List<String> outList = new ArrayList<String> ();
                    outList.add("OUT");

                    Predicate inpredicate = reasonexpression.in(inList);
                    Predicate outpredicate = reasonexpression.in(outList);

                    Expression<Number> sum = builder.sum(
                            builder.<Number>selectCase()  
                                 .when(inpredicate,qtyexpression.as(Double.class))  
                                 .when(outpredicate,builder.neg(qtyexpression).as(Double.class))  
                                 .otherwise(0));

return builder.equal(sum.as(Integer.class), 1)
}
```

Call it from as pageable

```
Page<Stockdiary> page = stockRepository.findAll(spec,pageable);
```

which is making below query :-

```
select count(stock0_.stock_id) as col_0_0_ from stock stock0_ cross join session_tbl session_tb1_ 
where stock0_.session_id=session_tb1_.session_id and 
cast(sum(case when stock0_.reason in (?) then stock0_.qty when stock0_.reason in (?) then -stock0_.qty else 101 end) as signed)=1 
group by stock0_.reason , stock0_.products_id , session_tb1_.terminal_id
```

I am getting SQL Exception due to `case` statement is after `where` clause. I dont know why spring put `case` after the `where` clause.

I am trying to make dynamic query, as i cant use static query.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are looking to perform a [Native Query](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/query_native.html).

In particular, you could use the **JPA** feature `SqlResultSetMapping` to define the mapping between your native query and the DTO object that can hold your data.

Assuming the DTO for your needs looks like this:

```
class ProductQuantity {
   private String product;
   private Integer quantity;

   public ProductQuantity(String product, Integer quantity) {
      this.product = product;
      this.quantity = quantity;
   }

   public getProduct() { return this.product; }

   public getQuantity() { return this.quantity; }
}
```

The following definition can act as a mapping for the native query:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
   name = "ProductQuantityMapping",
   classes = @ConstructorResult(
         targetClass = ProductQuantity.class,
         columns = {
            @ColumnResult(name = "product", type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "qty", type = Integer.class)
         })
)
```

And finally the query can be invoked as:

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT Product,SUM(CASE WHEN reason IN ('IN','REFUND') THEN Qty WHEN reason IN ('OUT','WASTE') THEN -Qty ELSE NULL END) AS Qty FROM stock GROUP BY Product");

List<ProductQuantity> result = q.getResultList();

for(ProductQuantity pq : result) {
   System.out.println("product: " + pq.getProduct() + ", Quantity: " + pq.getQuantity());
}
```

For more information/examples take a look at this [article](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-native-queries/).

Comment: i cant use entityManager, as per the requirement i have to use Spring Specification and Criteriabuilder only